# PHP tries to get http://getURL instead of what $_['getURL'] is assigned to

Tags: php, opencart

```
$_['getURL'] = 'http://example.com/hello';
$anothervariable = $this->language->get('getURL');
```

> API error format: could not resolve host: getURL

why on earth is it trying to go to http://getURL/ instead of the http://example.com/hello?

Any clues? TIA

Comment: Probably some effect with php's magic methods, here specifically the getter: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: What are you trying to do with $_['getURL'] ? it looks like that would attempt to create a variable named '$_' that's an array with the key 'getURL', but it doesn't seem like that works.. it creates a '$_' but it's just the string value.

Comment: Are you using OpenCart?

Comment: yes it is for opencart 3

Comment: The following code will set text from the language file as the heading title of the page:

$this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
This will grab the text for the variable $_['heading_title'] stored in the module's language file.

 If you need the text to be stored as a php session variable, use $this->session->data['text'] instead of $this->data['text'].

http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/developer/loading/

Answer (score 0):

In `->get('getURL')` `'getUrl'` is just a static hard-coded string, it doesn't refer to any other variable. And I'm unsure what `$_['getURL']` was supposed to be.

This:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/hello';
$anothervariable = $this->language->get($url);
```

probably makes more sense - declaring a variable and then passing it to the "get" function. (I'm assuming the "get" function is the one which tries to visit a URL.)

Comment: My guess was that `$_` is part of OpenCart or Twig, but I'm not familiar with either of them.

Comment: the MVC-L of opencart the language file has all these variables that get translated by the controller
$_['heading_title']
$_['heading_title_main']
http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/developer/module/